# nodejs not receiving request on forwarded port

Tags: port-forwarding, node.js, dyndns

I am trying to get my router to forward requests made to my noip dynamic dns to my local computer where I have a nodjs running, waiting for requests on port 14555.

I have the noip dns set up so that a netcat running locally does receive any calls made to port 14555 (i.e. with a browser):

```
ncat -l -n -v -v -k -p 14555
Ncat: Version 5.59BETA1 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Listening on 0.0.0.0:14555
Ncat: Connection from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56409.
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1430939580269-4 HTTP/1.1
Host: someDomain.ddns.net:14555
Connection: keep-alive
...
NCAT DEBUG: Closing connection.
Ncat: Connection from 84.167.116.141:56411.
```

However although the call seems to pass everything and arrives at my machine, node doesn't listen to it. It does not receive anything:

```
HTTP server listening at 0.0.0.0:14555/
```

My receiving server is configured like this:

```
var self = this;
// Start the server
this.httpServer = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 
    // Send HTML headers and message
    res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }); 
    res.end('<h1>Hello Socket Lover!</h1>');
});

//Listen on the port for HTTP requests
this.httpServer.listen(cfg.port, '0.0.0.0');

console.log('HTTP server listening at 0.0.0.0:' + cfg.port + '/');
```

Comment: I didn't vote to close your question, I voted to migrate it to http://stackoverflow.com . Unfortunately it didn't get the required support, so I suggest to re-ask your question there.

Comment: Please excuse my error. I was not aware that superuser and serverfault are divided by business/private environment. I have re-asked my question on Super User and Stackoverflow, since I feel it might be an error related to node or a missing step in between node and receiving the signal on the local machine. To others looking for the solution, search for the same name in these communities.

Comment: On my opinion, your question should have been migrated there. But the SE system dislikes migrations, probaby nobody knows, why.

Comment: Since it was not migrated:
I have found the answer and posted it [on super user](http://superuser.com/questions/911803/nodejs-not-receiving-request-on-forwarded-port/911857#911857)